# jQuery: Div and variable renders as [Object object] with .after()-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

So I'm making an A4-print-template for WordPress, and I'm using this code to create a new section (with A4-dimensions), copy the content and then put it into the new div with a margin, hiding the first part. You get it?
Well when I use `$(this).after("copyCon");` the variable renders fine. 
However, using the code below I get this:

```
<section class="4">

 [object Object]

</section>
```

JS:

```
var docWrap = $('.docWrap');
   var a4Height = '1046.920';
   var docCon = $('.docCon');

    function cropA4() {
        if ( $(this).height() > a4Height) {
            var copyCon = $(".docCon").clone().css({
        "margin-top": "-297mm"});
            $(this).after("<section class="a4">" + copyCon + "</section>");
        }
    }
    docWrap.each(cropA4);
```

Comment: 1. Check your quotes in `.after()` 2. `copyCon` is a jQuery object. How is this supposed to work with string concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the node copycon, using .html method.

```
var docWrap = $('.docWrap');
       var a4Height = '1046.920';
       var docCon = $('.docCon');

        function cropA4() {
            if ( $(this).height() > a4Height) {
                var copyCon = $(".docCon").clone().css({
            "margin-top": "-297mm"});
                $(this).after("<section class="a4">" + copyCon.html() + "</section>");
            }
        }
        docWrap.each(cropA4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will, "copyCon" is just text in one of the cases, you need to extract something from your jquery object, that is why you are seeing some of the `toString()` methods along the line.

Try with on of these below,

`$(this).after("<section class="a4">" + copyCon.val() + "</section>");`

or

`$(this).after("<section class="a4">" + copyCon.text() + "</section>");`

depends on what `docCon` is.